# ES6 Angular Controller class - unable to access $compile, $location etc

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

My ES6 Controller class is as follows. I am not able to execute the Angular methods like $compile, $location from the promise resolve part of the code. It is throwing the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$compile is not a function(…)" I am using arrow function to get the this access inside promise. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
import DashboardService from './DashboardService';

class DashboardController
{
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($scope, DashboardService, $location, $compile, PLATFORM) 
    {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.DashboardService = DashboardService;
        this.$location = $location;
        this.$compile = $compile;
        this.PLATFORM = PLATFORM;
    }

    UpdateGrid(clients)
    {
        this.PLATFORM.miraLoader.moduleImport('platform!kendo-ui').then((kendo) => {          
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: clients, pageSize: 10 });
            angular.element("#GridTest").kendoGrid({
                height: 415,
                scrollable: true,
                dataBound: function(){this.$compile(angular.element("#GridTest"))(this.$scope);}
            });
            var grid = angular.element("#GridTest").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
            grid.dataSource.read();
            this.$compile(angular.element("#GridTest"))(this.$scope);
        });
    }

    GoToClient(id){ this.$location.path('/Client/'+id); }

    AdvisorChange() {
        this.DashboardService.ClientsGet(this.wiquid, this.advisorid).then((clients) => {
            this.UpdateGrid(clients.data.d);
        });
    }
}   
export default DashboardController;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow operator ensures you can access `this.$compile()` inside the success callback for `then` but you're trying to access it from inside another callback `dataBound`.

You can do one of the following. In `UpdateGrid`:

```
const vm=this
```

then in the callback call `vm.$compile(...)`.

Or use:

```
dataBound: (function(){this.$compile(angular.element("#GridTest"))(this.$scope);}).bind(this)
```

to force `this` to have the expected value inside the `dataBound` callback.

Or you could put:

```
const $compile = this.$compile
```

in `UpdateGrid` and just call  `$compile(...)` from the callback.